Load environment variables from .env file in Bash
I'm trying to load environment variables from a file.env in Bash
Difficulties arise if the file contains complex variables.
Exemple file.env (variable NODE)
# DB 

; TEST
DB_USER=test
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_NAME=test

NODE='{"node0001": "127.0.0.1","node0002": "127.0.0.2","node0003": "127.0.0.3"}'

# API
API_PORT=8081
API_LOG=True
; FUNC_DEBUG=True

I tried the command xargs
export $(cat file.env | sed 's/#.*//g' | xargs)

I found another implementation
export ENV_FILE="file.env"

if [ -f "$ENV_FILE" ]; then

  echo "[INFO]: Reading $ENV_FILE file."

  while IFS= read -r line; do
    # Skip comments and empty lines
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^\s*#.*$ || -z "$line" ]]; then
      continue
    fi

    # Split the line into key and value
    key=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 1)
    value=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 2-)

    # Remove single quotes, double quotes, and leading/trailing spaces from the value
    value=$(echo "$value" | sed -e "s/^'//" -e "s/'$//" -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' -e 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//')

    # Export the key and value as environment variables
    export "$key=$value"
  done < "$ENV_FILE"
  echo "[DONE]: Reading $ENV_FILE file."
else
  echo "[ERROR]: $ENV_FILE not found."
fi

Both examples do not export variables very correctly.
I'm not good at bash, I don't fully understand how to do it better.
in the first example, when exporting
echo $NODE
{"v_edw2_node0001": 

must be
'{"node0001": "127.0.0.1","node0002": "127.0.0.2","node0003": "127.0.0.3"}'

Variables should be exported as specified, and lines starting with the # or ; character should be ignored (considered as a comment)

grep -Ev '^(;|#|$)' file.env   and try again, note DO NOT embed grep in the shell loop jfyi.

Also if you omit the IFS= then builtin read will discard leading and trailing spaces.

Your code says strip surrounding quotes but your text says keep them ("$NODE must be ..."). Which is it?

If you don't care about warnings and are running a modern version of bash (4+):
mapfile lines <file.env
export "${lines[@]}"

Or you can strip the non-definition lines and trim whitespace with:
mapfile defs <(
    sed '
        s/^[[:space:]]*//
        s/[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*/=/
        /^[a-zA-Z_]\{1,\}=/!d
        s/[[:space:]]*$//
    ' file.env
)
export "${defs[@]}"

If you are running bash 3, mapfile can become a read loop:
while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ ^[[:space:]]*([a-zA-Z_]+)[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*((.*[^[:space:]])?)[[:space:]]*$ ]] &&
    export "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done <file.env

Adjust the regex if your variables can include digits, or mustn't start with _, etc; or if you want to be more precise in which lines are processed.
Your sample doesn't have definitions spanning multiple lines. If your real data does, this code won't work.

There seems to be no problem with your 'complex variable'. The problem is in the comment lines starting with a ;.
Remove that lines or replace the semicolon by a #.
After that, the variables appear right in the shell. No need for fiddling with the quotes, since they are correct already.
If you really need the ;-comment lines, preprocess the file by replacing the semicolons.

I replaced the ; symbol on # in the file.new and used script
filePath="${1:-file.env}"

if [ ! -f "$filePath" ]; then
  return 0
fi

while read -r line; do
  if [[ "$line" =~ ^\s*#.*$ || -z "$line" ]]; then
    continue
  fi

  key=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 1 | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')
  value=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 2- | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')

  export "$key=$value"

done < "$filePath"


paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation, recommendation...

If you can modify the file.env file, then you could use it like a script:
# DB
export DB_USER=test
export DB_HOST=localhost
export DB_PORT=5432
export DB_NAME=test

export NODE=$'\'{"node0001": "127.0.0.1","node0002": "127.0.0.2","node0003": "127.0.0.3"}\''

# API
export API_PORT=8081
export API_LOG=True
# export FUNC_DEBUG=True

For taking the env to use, just run:
source file.env

Or even simplier:
. file.env

Example result:
~ # . /tmp/file.env
~ # env | grep -E "(NODE|DB_|API_)"
API_PORT=8081
DB_PORT=5432
DB_NAME=test
API_LOG=True
NODE='{"node0001": "127.0.0.1","node0002": "127.0.0.2","node0003": "127.0.0.3"}'
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=test
~ #


Ok, answer modified to use $'  instead of "

This version of the env file is not suitable (with export) because it is also used in the python script
